# Can I use purrr to execute a dplyr query and save the result of each query output

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have the following dataset:

```
combined <- data.frame(
  client = c('aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','bbb','ccc','ccc','ddd','ddd','ddd'),
  type = c('norm','reg','opt','norm','norm','reg','opt','opt','opt','reg'),
  age = c('>50','>50','75+','<25','<25','>50','75+','25-50','25-50','75+'),
  cases = c('1','2','2','1','0','1','2','0','3','2'),
  IsActive = c('1','0','0','1','1','0','1','1','1','0')
)
```

And have identified the unique variable combinations with :

```
# get unique variable combinations
unique_vars <- combined %>%
  select(1:3,5) %>%
  distinct()
```

I am trying to iterate on this query `combined %>% anti_join(slice(unique_vars,1))` using `purrr` and save both the output of the query and also save summary of `cases` from each output back to the `unique_vars` table.  The slice should iterate through each row of unique_vars, not be fixed at 1

I tried :

```
qry <- combined %>% anti_join(slice(unique_vars,1))


map(.x = unique_vars %>%
      slice(.),
      ~qry %>%
      summarise(CaseCnt = sum(cases)) %>%
      inner_join(.x))
```

My desired output would be two things:

1. Full output of the query
2. the new Field CaseCnt added to the unique_vars dataframe

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't completely follow the intuition behind your query, it seems that for #1 you would want:

```
lapply(1:nrow(unique_vars), function(x) {
  combined %>% 
    anti_join(slice(unique_vars, x), keep = TRUE)
})
```

And for #2 you would want:

```
unique_vars$CaseCnt <- lapply(1:nrow(unique_vars), function(x) {
  combined %>% 
    anti_join(slice(unique_vars, x), keep = TRUE) %>%
    summarise(CaseCnt = sum(cases %>% as.numeric))
}) %>% do.call(what = rbind.data.frame, 
               args = .)
```

Alternatively for #2 with `purrr:map_df()`:

```
unique_vars$CaseCnt <- map_df(c(1:nrow(unique_vars)), function(x) {
  combined %>% 
    anti_join(slice(unique_vars, x), keep = TRUE) %>%
    summarise(CaseCnt = sum(cases %>% as.numeric))
})
```

---

Just as an aside -- you could do this directly with:

```
combined %>% 
  mutate(cases = as.numeric(cases)) %>%
  mutate(tot_cases = sum(cases)) %>%    # sum total cases across unique_id's
  group_by(client, type, age, IsActive) %>%
  summarize(CaseCnt = mean(tot_cases) - sum(cases))
```

Or if what you were actually looking for is the sum of cases in that group:

```
combined %>% 
  mutate(cases = as.numeric(cases)) %>%
  group_by(client, type, age, IsActive) %>%
  summarize(CaseCnt = sum(cases))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this.  I tried your last suggestion - which seems like it could work, however it doesn't sum the cases according to the groups correctly.  It looks like it is summing the cases for the original group_by, not considering the unique_id.  I tried to ungroup() and group_by() after the mutate but that didn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Just cleaned up that code - does this get at what your after?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Using that, it summarizes the total cases for all the data, not by group which is ultimately what I need.  For example in the initial data set client 'aaa' and type 'norm' has 1 case, but using your original suggestion it creates the CaseCnt of 2 for that row

Comment: Did you check the updated post? I believe the code (as it is) would return 13, not 2. Maybe to help clarify, what number do you expect for that group?

Comment: For that group, based on the combined dataset the sum of cases should be 1.

Comment: based on your use of `anti_join()` in your question, it seemed like you were looking for sum of cases out side of the variables in your `slice()` to be associated with that slice... I've added code to get the sum of cases from a group, but I'm still unclear on what you are looking for with your query.. If this isn't what you're looking for it would help to add to your question the form of your desired output.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly.  Thanks for your help & time!